# How to call a voice xml application?

Tags: text-to-speech, vxml, voicexml

I have a local installation of Voxeo's Prophecy platform, and a voice xml application that runs on the voicexml browser of the platform. How can i call the application to listen to the message, without having a sip phone, and without using the voxeo's hosting capability? I just want to call the application at the local installation without using a phone. When i try this from the browser, i just get the xml file containing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to start the application without a SIP phone?  The developer version of Prophecy comes with a SIP phone that works great for testing and debugging.  Are you trying to access the application from a regular telephone or POTS.  If that is the case you will need additional hardware, such as a Cisco VoIP Gateway to translate the land-line signal to SIP.  There are a number of VoIP Gateways available.  Another option is to put Dialogic cards in your server and use a software that translates between SIP and the Dialogic API.  If you purchase Prophecy from Voxeo as an appliance there are options they can sell you to achieve this. The advantage of getting this from Voxeo is that they will help configure it, which is not trivial depending upon the type type of telephone lines you are using and whether they are behind a PBX or not.

The telephony/communications interface to Prophecy is SIP so that is the only way to communicate with it.  You could use any open source SIP stacks to develop something yourself, but the easiest thing to do is to use a software based SIP phone.  It is not like you could just start talking and the VXML app would know what you intended, or if the if the voice input was really intended for the VXML app.  You still need to maintain things like sessions and routing to the correct application which is easily handled by a SIP phone.  Prophecy is designed for a telephony environment.  If you are trying to use it for something like a home automation system, which some people have, I would think you would have to provide some type of SIP front end that is voice activated.

Comment: In fact, i want to have an open voice channel which will be the Voice User Interface for my application. The server runs locally and there is no need for a sip phone. I would prefer to just talk to the microphone and transfer the voice commands to my application. If i use a sip phone, i will always have to check if the sip phone is still running, if the call is on etc. It is just extra work and problems that could arise. Thank you